# Prove by vector method that the diagonals of a rhombus bisect each other. Also, show that they bisect each other at right angles.

Tags: geometry, vectors

Prove by vector method that the diagonals of a rhombus bisect each other. Also, show that they bisect each other at right angles

My Attempt:

Let us consider a rhombus $OACB$ where $\vec {OA}=\vec {a}$ and $\vec {OB}= \vec {b}$. 
Then, 
$$\vec {OC}=\vec {OA} + \vec {AC}$$
$$\vec {OC}=\vec {OA} + \vec {OB}$$
$$\vec {OC}=\vec {a} + \vec {b}$$
Similarly for $\vec {AB}$ we can write $\vec {AB}=\vec {b} - \vec {a}$.

Comment: For the first part, show that $\frac12\vec{OC}$, the half-way point of diagonal $\vec{OC}$, is the same as the half-way point of diagonal $\vec{AB}$, which is at $\vec{OA}+\frac12\vec{AB}$.

Comment: Go on. Do you realize what you need to show in terms  of the vectors you have defined? Compute those quantities, then if you are stuck get back.

Comment: For the second part, look at the scalar product of $\vec{OC}$ and $\vec{AB}$.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that $$\frac12 \vec{OC} = \vec{OA}+\frac12\vec{AB}$$

The left hand side is $\frac12(\vec{a}+\vec{b})$.

The right hand side is $\vec{a}+\frac12(\vec{b}-\vec{a})=\frac12(\vec{a}+\vec{b})$.

Hence, we have shown that they bisect each other.

Answer (score 0):

To show that the diagonals cross at right angles you need to show that

$\vec{OC}\cdot\vec{AB} = (\vec a + \vec b) \cdot (\vec  b- \vec a)=0$

You will need to use the fact that $|a|=|b|$, because this property is true for a rhomubs but not for a general parallelogram.

To show that the diagonals bisect one another you need to express $\vec b$ as a linear combination of $\vec a+ \vec b$ and $\vec b - \vec a$. In other words find constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that

$\vec b = \alpha(\vec a + \vec b) +\beta (\vec  b- \vec a)$

Note that this property *is* true for a general parallelogram, so it does not depend on the fact that $|a|=|b|$ for a rhombus.

Comment: would you please elaborate more on how to show they bisect ?

Comment: If the diagonals bisect each other then $\vec{OB} = \frac 1 2 \vec{OC} + \frac 1 2 \vec{AB}$.

Comment: How are we going to get the values of $\alpha $ and $\beta $?